# How to delete all mails of user in linux(centos)

Tags: email, postfix

I have postfix running on centos 6.3 server i have 4 user on this server i used these user to handle bounce mails. i use a php application which process the bounce and delete mails on hourly basis but due to some problem in cron the php application did not process the bounce and due to this one of user have around 10 lacks mail in inbox so i need to delete them manually i used a command for this but unfortunately i have missed the command now i have googled about this command but not able to find out the exact one.

```
           **> /var/spool/mail/user**
```

But this is not working for me please suggest me the solution for this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possible mail storage mechanisms, so it's hard to give a general answer.  IF nothing in particular has been set up for this though, then it's likely that you're storing mail in mbox format in /var/mail/user, or perhaps it's /var/spool/mail/user.  IF you have verified that that's where the mail is being stored, then you cna just delete the files, or truncate them.

It looks like what you wrote above might be meant to be this command to truncate a file:

```
:> /var/spool/mail/user
```

`:` is a builtin command found in several common shells, which produces no output.  so you pipe that to the file, and it overwrites the content with nothing.